# Calendar operations over a list of users - Java

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with the logic over a list of users (from a build-in db).

So i have this:

```
public class User extends BaseEntity<String> {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date accountCreated;
    private Date accountLogin;
    private UserDetails userDetails;
}
```

The method below should be returning all users with the age above 18.

```
public  List<User> findByAge(){
        List<User> users = findAll();
        List<User> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer systemYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        for(User user : users) {

            calendar.setTime(user.getUserDetails().getBirthDate());
            Integer userYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            if ((systemYear - userYear) > 18)
                tempList.add(user);
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, String.format("{%d} user(s) were found with age above 18", tempList.size()));
        return tempList;
    }
```

The unit test is this:

```
 @Test
public  void testFindByAge() throws Exception {
User user = userService.findAll().get(0);
user.setAccountCreated(UserTestUtils.buildDate(1990, 3, 3)); 
Assert.assertNotNull(userService.findByAge());
    }
```

Details:

```
 public static Date buildDate(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

I did spend some time on this and i could really use some help finding out where the bug is

Comment: First problem: `if ((systemYear - userYear) > 18)` doesn't find users over 18. Consider someone who was born in January 1997 vs December 1997, with respect to July 2015... one is over 18 and one is under 18.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jon. How can I fix this? I've been looking at different posts to how i can get this done previously to asking this question. 

What's the way to get this done ? For exampe in the unit test the entry should clearly return a user with the age above 18

I'm sure there is a better way to perform these operations (the age example is just one case), so i'm looking for a better approach to conduct these operations

Comment: Well, I'd personally start by using Joda Time or java.time instead of `Date` and `Calendar`. I'd then *also* look for a way of abstracting "the current time" as something you can set in your unit test. (I like having a `Clock` interface with methods to return the current time - then you can fake it in tests.)

Comment: I'll start looking at Joda Time as you suggested. Still don't know why i don't get the expected results after running the test:

,,,,,,user.UserRepositoryImpl findByAge
INFO: {0} user(s) were found with age above 18

I still have a bug somewhere in the app and it drives me crazy

Comment: Well without seeing a short but *complete* program, it's somewhat hard to say. I note that in the unit test you're setting the account created date rather than the birth date, mind you... was that deliberate?

Comment: You are rigth that was big mistake on my side. Modified it to 

@Test
    public  void testFindByAge() throws Exception {
        User user = userService.findAll().get(0);
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
        userDetails.setBirthDate(UserTestUtils.buildDate(1990, 3, 3));
        Assert.assertNotNull(userService.findByAge());

    }

still the same result  - 0 users found 

thank you for the observation i'll take another look at everything else and i'll evaluate it.

Comment: Right now, from a logical perspective:

1. Either there is a bug in my UT
2. The list (tempList) that i use to store the users doesn't get "populated"

Thank you again for your feedback on this, really appreciate your help and got me some new perspectives.

Comment: Sorry for spamming, wanted to say I fixed the prob, it was something in the UT that i forgot. 

However thanks again, your help was much appreciated Jon.